# At edges last 2 dots of dotted borders mixing to each other in Safari for iphone and ipad, any solution?

Tags: css, safari, mobile-safari, mobile-website

For example see edges in this image. where red arrow is indicating

[image]

Any solution for this?

Comment: Not sure how this is specific to CSS3...

Answer (score 2):

This has to do with a rendering bug in Mobile Safari, although I can't find any sort of error reporting on this subject.

A not so nice solution would be to fake the styling with a background image.